# Docker-compose with Loopback and Mongodb fail to connect mongdb

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, loopback

I have been learning docker lately and I was unable to make a connection between my loopback api and mongodb. The application works fine in local dev environment. With docker-compose my mongodb server runs at `localhost:27017` and my react-frontend serves at `localhost:3000` and looks fine. Only loopback is unable to connect to mongodb and throws the following errors:

```
loopback_1  | Web server listening at: http://localhost:8080
loopback_1  | Browse your REST API at http://localhost:8080/explorer
loopback_1  | Connection fails: MongoError: failed to connect to server 
[localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 
127.0.0.1:27017]
loopback_1  | It will be retried for the next request.
loopback_1  | 
loopback_1  | /opt/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:421
loopback_1  |           throw err
loopback_1  |           ^
loopback_1  | MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] 
on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
loopback_1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> 
(/opt/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
```

Here is my **Dockerfile** for **Loopback-API**

```
FROM node:6

RUN mkdir -p /opt/src/app

WORKDIR  /opt/src/app

COPY package.json /opt/src/app

RUN npm cache clean

RUN npm install

COPY . /opt/src/app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My **docker-compose** file looks like this:

```
    version: '3.0' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  database: # name of first service
      image: mongo # specify the image to build container from
      ports:
        - "27017:27017" # specify port forwarding

  loopback: # name of second service
      build: myapp_backend # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8080:8080" # specify port mapping
      links:
        - database # link this service to the database service

  react: # name of third service
      build: myapp_frontend # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "3000:3000" #specify port mapping
```

And finally **datasource** file in loopback-api looks like this:

```
    {
  "db": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test",
    "password": "",
    "name": "mongoDS",
    "user": "",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your datasource file should have:

`"host": "database"
...`

since in docker-compose.yml you link mongo container to loopback as `database`, so it's not `localhost`. Remember, you are trying to connect to mongo from loopback docker container. Also you should make sure that mongo is started before loopback, so add `depends_on: database` to loopback service in docker-compose.yml.